# One-way data bind in GridView/DetailsView

Tags: data-binding, gridview, detailsview

In my **GridView/DetailsView** (using templates) if I use **Eval** I get the value from the database and siplay to the grid. If I use **Bind** I get the value from the database and upon submit I write it in the database.

Is there any way just not to display the value but to write it (upon update) in the database? An **Eval** function that works the other way around.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your GridView/DetailsView, create a Column with a Hiddenfield. If you don't want the extra blank space that the column creates, you can hide the column.

```
    <Columns>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
             <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" Value='<%# Bind("myValue") %>'
 runat="server" />
             </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
```

I hope this helps.